# cpu rendering graphics instead of ati hd 5470

Tags: 12.10, graphics, cpu

Ubuntu 12.10 is really burning my laptop.I have an vaio laptop with ati hd 5470,i3  370m processor.Processor is used to render unity launcher transparent windows.Cpu usage is close to 100 whenever I use unity launcher or watch a video.I think cpu is being used to do all the rendering.

Comment: So what is the specific question here?

Answer (score 1):

My laptop (hd 5470, i5 m480) had the same heating problem. The installation of the proprietary ati driver failed and the open source radeon driver has poor powermanagement.

I know you asked the completely opposite but disabling the hd 5470 really helped with the heat.

To do this first look if you can disable this grapics card in your bios. If there isn't such an option you can do this:

If you have the proprietary driver installed remove them and use the open source driver. Then open a terminal and type

```
gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and insert the following line before exit 0

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

Then reboot your system.

The second solution has (at least on my laptop) the disadvantage that suspend isn't working anymore.

Hope this helps:)